# Pressed Approve instead of Reject and banned for one month

Tags: support, review-audits, review-suspension

I have been reviewing **Suggested Edits Review Queue**, on [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23446723) which is pretty obvious to reject I pressed accidentally on approve.

- I failed only once and got a warning beforehand.
- Got banned for a **month**.

> Reviewer Stats
>
> Dennis Vash has approved 227 edit suggestions and rejected 13 edit suggestions and improved 19 edit suggestions

I wanted to ask a few things:

- Is it possible to reduce the ban for a decent duration like a week?
- Is there any "support" channel for situations like this?

Comment: Without checking your reviews, by looking at those numbers only, it does look you are should be rejecting/skipping **much** more often.

Comment: Does it a stupid question and should delete it?

Comment: Failing a single audit does not immediately result in a 30-day ban, afaik.

Comment: That's up to you. No need to delete it if you want to get feedback. Votes in meta do not affect your account or reputation in any way.

Comment: Were you banned before, or is it your first ban? If you were previously banned, it means you haven't learn how to review effectively since your last ban. If it's your first ban, it means a moderator applied the review ban directly because your review history doesn't show good judgement so far, and it's better for you (and the site) if you take a time-out to better understand how you should be reviewing.

Comment: I have been banned for a week on another queue and stopped reviewing there. So I have been reviewing only edits for the past week, and on the second fail got banned as mentioned

Comment: There are at least three other reviews from the last 24h that are problematic: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23438488): changes "if it's possible" to "if is possible". You accepted an edit that introduces wrong grammar. [2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23446544) Comment says "provide some more details" but editor has added a wrong punctation to the title.  Sentences never end with .? [3](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23437884) Editor copied title to body.

Comment: Got it, I wasn't familiar with this thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You review pretty fast, according to the timestamps of your most recent reviews:

> 2019-07-05 08:51:25Z
>   2019-07-05 08:51:18Z
>   2019-07-05 08:51:14Z
>   2019-07-05 08:51:09Z
>   2019-07-05 08:51:06Z
>   2019-07-05 08:50:51Z
>   2019-07-05 08:50:44Z

Besides the audit, you also approved [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23446544) while it should have been rejected.

A 30-day ban usually means you've been review banned before. Assuming best intent, you should slow down and take the time to properly review the suggested edits. Don't keep your cursor hovering over the *Approve* button.

Comment: Why do you think linked one should be rejected. He has corrected a grammar mistake. Yes, it is very small. But still better than nothing.

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson What grammar mistake? There is no case in the English language that I know of where a period is directly followed by a question mark....

Comment: @IAmThe Even if they **had** fixed a small grammar mistake (they didn't), fixing a small but irrelevant grammar mistake in an otherwise closable/deletable question it's a waste of time for everyone.